# How to Implement Many to Many Relationship with Different Database in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 tables:

1. subdistrict (in database B)
2. users (in database A)
3. admin_area (in database A).

and now, i want to insert or display data for user with area. below is the code i have made:

Model User

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Marketplace\Subdistrict;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles, SoftDeletes;

    public function areas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subdistrict::class, 'admin_area', 'user_id', 'subdistrict_id');
    }

}
```

Model Subdistrict

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Marketplace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subdistrict extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'marketplace';
    
    protected $table = 'subdistrict';

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'admin_area', 'user_id', 'subdistrict_id');
    }
}
```

admin_area table:

- user_id
- subdistrict_id

If I try to get the areas from user_id = 1, I get an error like below
[image]

How to fix it? or How to make pivot table with different database in laravel 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring any design considerations, you can try by including the database name in front of the table. I'm assuming that the databases are in the same server.
Try alternating database_a or database_b (I'm not 100% clear on how the relationship was created).

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles, SoftDeletes;

    public function areas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subdistrict::class, 'database_a.admin_area', 'user_id', 'subdistrict_id');
    }

}
```